# What is this tropical plant?

Tags: identification, fruit-trees, tropical

I'm very interested in knowing the name of this tree. Does one of the pictures show a type of fruit, the green cluster dropping down from the branch?

[image: 1]: [![https://i.stack.imgur.com/12E1D.jpg]

[image: tropical shrub]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly the hybrid *Carica x pentagona*, also known as Babaco.
The taxonomy seems somewhat confused, with many references giving the name as *Vasconcellea x heilbornii* or just *Carica pentagona*.
The Plant List shows *Carica x pentagona* is the accepted name.

Note: The link below does not show any images- it is a 'working list' of plant names and is the most up to date and reliable resource I know for checking validity of taxonomic epithets. I included it here just because there is so much variation in internet references around the taxonomy of Babaco.

http://www.theplantlist.org/tpl1.1/record/kew-2700929

**Edit:** (following @Sue's comment below)
Here is another link with some more info and images:

https://davesgarden.com/guides/pf/go/74196/#b

The images below are from the Daleys Fruit Tree site.

https://www.daleysfruit.com.au/buy/babaco-tree.htm

[image: Babaco fruit]

[image: Babaco leaf]

[image: Babaco plant]

Comment: Hi Ben W! Would you please help me with your resources? The first one shows a name, but I can't seem to find a picture on that page. The second source, Daley's fruit, shows me a picture of some fruit covering most of a leaf. When I click to get a closer look at any of the linked pictures below that, my computer tells me it's an unsafe site and likely to give me a virus. I use Webroot security software, and I trust it. The identification seems right, but would you mind adding some other links for clarification? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Sue, I have updated my answer. Not sure why you got virus warnings from the Daleys site. I have Norton and had no issues. I have added the images from the site directly into my answer.

Comment: Thanks Ben! This looks great, and I appreciate you taking the time to do it. I don't know what happened with my Webroot either. Most of the plant sites are fine, and I'm not sure why this would be different. This is a fascinating plant! I definitely haven't seen it before.